# Can my app access to the Facebook friend list of my users' friends?

Tags: facebook, facebook-friends

I am trying to know if it is possible for my app to access to its users' second degree friends (the friend of the friend of my user).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tis is not possible in the Graph API, and as far as I know never was.